# JavaScript: delete product from cart with minus button

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, cart

I'm trying to eliminate the product added to the cart using the "-" button when the quantity reaches 1 unit. I hope someone can help me, I've been looking for a solution for two days. Thanks in advance.

```
//changeNumber

function changeNumber(action, id){

cart = cart.map((item)=> {

let = oldNumber = item.numberOfUnits;

if(item.id === id){

  if (action === "meno" && item.numberOfUnits >1) {
 oldNumber--
  } else if (action === "piu") {
    oldNumber++
     } 

     if (action === "meno" && item.numberOfUnits === 1){

       console.log("delete")
      console.log(cart.splice(item.id, 1));      
      }


updateCart();

}

return {
  ...item,
  numberOfUnits: oldNumber,
 
}

});


updateCart();
}
```

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, your asking how to have the number of units decrease by 1, until it hits one, at which point it should be completely removed (as apposed to having a unit count of 0)?

Answer (score 2):

The map function will not let you delete elements while it is looping.

There are two approches:

1. Save the index of what you want to delete, and then after the .map(), call `delete cart[index]`
2. Use a different technique to update the cart list **(recommended)**

## Technique #1

```
function changeNumber(action, id) {
    var toRemove = null;
    var index = 0;

    [...]

    // Instead of the two console.logs
    toRemove = index;

    [...]

    // At the end of the map lambda
    index++;

    [...]

    // At the end of the changeNumber function
    if (toRemove !== null)
        delete cart[toRemove];
}
```

## Technique #2

Instead of an array, use an object `{id: item}`. This allows you to access and modify a specific element without having to loop through everything.

```js
var cart = {};

function addToCart(item) {
    if (item.id in cart) // Check if the item is already in the cart
        cart[item.id].numberOfUnits++;
    else {
        cart[item.id] = item; // You may want to copy the item instead of directly adding it
        item.numberOfUnits = 1; // May be unnecessary or unwanted, depending on your system
    }
}

function removeFromCart(item) {
    if (!(item.id in cart)) // If the item is already not in the cart
        return false; // The removal was already done
    cart[item.id].numberOfUnits--;
    if (cart[item.id].numberOfUnits <= 0) // The less-than is unnecessary, but a good check anyway
        delete cart[item.id];
    return true; // The removal was successful
}

// Example
addToCart({id: 5});
addToCart({id: 5});
addToCart({id: 7});

console.log(removeFromCart({id: 5})); // True; there was an item to remove
console.log(removeFromCart({id: 7})); // True; there was an item to remove
console.log(removeFromCart({id: 7})); // False; there was no item

console.log(cart);
```

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementById('phone-minus').addEventListener('click', function(){

```
        console.log('minus done');

        const phoneMinusVal=document.getElementById('case-number');
        const phNum=phoneMinusVal.value;

        if(phNum>0)
        phoneMinusVal.value=parseInt(phNum)-1;
        
    })
```